# Is it possible to use the same domain for a Windows Azure site and on-premise virtual directory app?

Tags: networking, azure

Or, in other words, is it posible to have the following configuration?

www.mysite.com -> access the site published on windows azure myapp.cloudapp.net.
www.mysite.com/otherapp -> access the site published on an on-premise server.

If yes, how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - as long as you own the `mysite.com` domain, this could be accomplished using DNS entries and a reverse proxy server. Below is a schematic diagram.

[image]

You can point the DNS entry for `www.mysite.com` to a [reverse proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). This could reside in the cloud or on-premise. An example of doing this with [nginx is here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html), but you could do this with IIS, Apache, or most other web servers.

In your reverse proxy setup, you can rewrite the URL so that requests to the `www.mysite.com` root go to your Windows Azure service listening at `mysite.cloudapp.net`. Likewise, requests to `www.mysite.com/otherapp` can be rewritten to go to your server(s) on-premise.

Comment: Thanks!, I would like to confirm if this config could work over SSL also? basically `https://mysite.com/otherapp` I believe that in this case the proxy would be the one with the certificate?

Comment: Yes - that's correct. The proxy would have the cert. You can continue SSL to the Azure or on-premise server also if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, at least without using reverse proxy from Azure to on-premise.

You could use **subdomain**, though:

www.mysite.com -> access the site published on windows azure myapp.cloudapp.net. otherapp.mysite.com -> access the site published on an on-premise server.